# Why am I getting Json Malformed Exception

Tags: java, android, arrays, json, api

I have an android app which does some network process in the background, requesting information from json api at https://ipinfo.io/json. The bufferReader `httpConnection` is successfully made, and `BufferReader` contains the information which I later add into output String (while loop).

Now when converting into the json object..

```
String INTERNET_IP_SOURCE = "https://ipinfo.io/json"
```

is declare globally. I'm getting exception about malformed json object. What am I missing here? Thanks!

```
private class TaskPublicNet extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Void> {
    String output = "";
    int progress = 0;
    String json = "";
    //only 7 lines of information for public ip info (set progress at 5)
    final static int PROGRESS_MAX = 5;
    String[] iface;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progressBar.setMax(PROGRESS_MAX);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        progressBar.setProgress(1);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        progressBar.setProgress(5);
        Log.v("ALL ", localIfaceInfo.toString());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
        Log.v("PROGRESS ", values[0]);
        localIfaceInfo.add(values[0]);
        localNetAdapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        /** Getting public interface information*/
        try {
            // Make a URL to the web page
            URL url = new URL(INTERNET_IP_SOURCE);
            // Get the input stream through URL Connection
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            String line = "";
            // read each line and write to System.out
            while ((line = bf.readLine()) != null) {
                Log.v("LINE ", line);
                output += line;
            }
            bf.close();
        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        //json parsing
        try {

            JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(output);
            JSONObject jo = (JSONObject) ja.get(0);
            String publicIp = jo.get("ip").toString();
            String city = jo.get("city").toString();
            String provider = jo.get("org").toString();
            Log.v("PUBLIC ", publicIp +" "+city+" "+provider);
            publishProgress("Public Ip: "+publicIp);
            publishProgress("City: "+city);
            publishProgress("Provider: "+provider);
        }
        catch (JSONException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: please add the crash logs

Comment: You are loading the output in a `JSONArray`, while the URL returns a `JSONObject`.

Answer (score 3):

the response looks like this

```
{
  "ip": "XXXXXX",
  "city": "",
  "region": "",
  "country": "XX",
  "loc": "XXXXX,XXXXX",
  "org": "XXXXXXXX"
}
```

but in your code you are doing this

```
 JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(output);
 JSONObject jo = (JSONObject) ja.get(0);
```

The json is an object is not an array. Try parsing it directly into an object

```
JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(output)
```

Comment: when I debug in android studio using Log.v it looks like a string or String array, not a json object.. but thanks

Comment: Hmm interesting. i just called this url and it returned this. So anyway even if thats not the problem i would make sure you are able to handle it